# How to continuously monitor changes in a file using python

Tags: python, linux, pyinotify

I have to monitor for changes in a file and run relevant logic for any change event. 
I tried to use pyinotify package but after the first it stops notifying.

```
import pyinotify

class ModHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    # evt has useful properties, including pathname
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, evt):
            print('lior')

def registerChanges():
    print('start run notifyer')
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    wm.add_watch("/home/vagrant/Desktop/test.txt", pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
    handler = ModHandler()
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
    notifier.loop()

registerChanges()
```

Thanks

Comment: check what python version you running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)