# Indexing files on fileserver using os.walk()

Tags: python

Hoi!

I am indexing files on a file-server using os.walk() (check certain files for their content and then adding them to a list to be reviewed later). It works quite nicely for a smaller folders, but to do the whole thing it takes quite some time (>1h) and there is constantly data added to the server.

How does this impact my indexing? What files will be included? The ones that happen to be in a certain location, when it is scanned? I am mainly interested in a "snapshot" at a certain moment in time.

Thank you!

Kind regards,

Sebastian

This is the code I am using currently. is there maybe a better/faster way to do this?

```
inport os

file_list = []
for current_folder, sub_folders, file_names in os.walk(my_path):
    for file in file_names:
        if file == "title":
            with open(os.path.join(current_folder, file), "r") as f:
                title = f.read()
            file_list.append([file, current_folder, title])
```

Comment: use file event instead of loop file system yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not really care that much about the new files. I want to check all existing ones and to understand what happens if the folders and contents change, while I am searching them.

Comment: Hey! From what I understand, you want to index on a snapshot of the file system. If any OS+file system supports this, of course it would be very slow. I think you can make a simple algorithm like walk that uses a hash function to check if it shall follow a specific route on the file system tree. Some software like git and robocopy use this kind of logic.  But I'm pretty sure what you need is already implemented out there.

Comment: If you want to check if another application is manipulating a file while you are walking by it. I think you have to use some kind of IPC, you can also lock on files https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out!