# Watching TXT file updates through Python

Tags: python, winapi, readdirectorychangesw

I'm working on a python program that should wait for another program to update a `.txt` file, and when the file was updated my program should open it, get the command the other program just made, and then run something else. I'm quite new to python so a generic but well-explained solution would be great.

I've found [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes) that leads to the solution [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html), but I can't quite understand how this works. The program could also be in other languages but it should trigger my python modules.

Here's the general idea of what I'm looking for.

```py
sub GET_FILE_UPDATE:  
try:  
    while change == False:  
       time.sleep(1)  
    else  
       if change == True  
       'open file and read command'  
       run.command()  
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  
       'stop program'
```

Comment: [os.path.getmtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) returns the last modification timestamp. Does a change of that metadata means the file was "modified" (even if the contents did not change)?

Comment: The problem is underspecified. You'll need to explain what condition constitutes that this other program is done updating the file in question. That's one stop towards your solution.

Comment: The ideia is that the other program will keep the file open in a blocked mode so that my program can not open it until it updates the file and closes it, so i would have to wait for this to be done so then i would open and get the line the program just wrote in the txt file.

Comment: It can be done, for example, using [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationa) API. What you need to understand the API and code sample for Python you have already found.