# How to watch a directory for saved files using watchdog

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-watchdog

I'm on a mac. My program monitors a directory, and I already have listeners in place for `on_created`
and `on_deleted`, but I need to also detect when a file is saved and run a **different** function then. Is this possible using watchdog **without** platform-specific tools?

---

**[NOTE]** I know that I can use `on_modified` handler function, but that is also called when a file is created. I only want to detect when the content of the file changes, not when a file is created or deleted

**[NOTE]** note also that I need to watch a whole directory **and all subdirectories** and not just a single file

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)

Comment: I know that I can use ```on_modified``` handler function, but that is also called when a file is created. I only want to detect when the content of the file changes, not when a file is created or deleted