# How do I check if a text file has new content in Python?

Tags: python, text-files

I'm writing a program in which I need the program to verify if there is new content in a file. If the file HAS content, but the content has already been viewed previously by the user, it doesn't count as a notification, but if it is new, it is shown to the user.

How do I do this?

Comment: sounds like this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)? maybe, you can try the solution posted there?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/)?

> Python API library and shell utilities to monitor file system events.

Directory monitoring made easy with:

> - A cross-platform API.
> - A shell tool to run commands in response to directory changes.
>   Get started quickly with a simple example in [Quickstart](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#quickstart)...

Comment: If you are going to copy the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes, at least reference it.