# Scripts result to a other script on a other pc (python)

Tags: python, connection

So Im a beginner in coding and I was wondering if there is away to send script results to a other script on a other pc and how to let the second script (the script thats recieving the results) WAIT until it gets result so yea thats my first question since I couldnt find any answers on yt or on stackoverflow or google

Comment: What connection do you have available between the two computers? Do they share storage or a network?

Comment: They dont share a network and they dont share a storage

Comment: They would need some way of transmitting the data in order to do what you want on two computers. But you could practice the communication between two scripts that you describe on a single computer, if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

It is a really interesting problem you are trying to tackle, and something that is still actively being developed solutions for (e.g. cloud computing).

First of all, you need a way of transferring data between the two computers in order to automatically start a script on a computer when a result has been generated on another computer.

You could utilize a [ssh connection](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/server) if both computers have an internet connection.

Alternatively, you use an USB drive to store the result on, and manually insert it into the second computer with a program able to recognize that the USB drive has become available.

In regards to coding this, I believe what you are looking for what is called a *listener*. You can find some solutions to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes).