# Using a service as an input to a program

Tags: python

I want to program a Windows service that will detect when a .png or .jpg file has been added to a specific folder and then send a Boolean value to another program that will take these pictures and process them.

I am not sure if there is a better way for a program to passively scan for input files or how to get a service to communicate with a program.

Comment: I think you are right, the only way to do that would be to poll the folder every `x` milliseconds.

Comment: See the use of [```watchdog```](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/create-a-watchdog-in-python) module

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes ?

Comment: The watchdog one looks much more promising than trying to implement a service. Thank you.