# Print Contents of File When Updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and I would like to know how to continuously print the contents of a file every time it's updated. So, I do not want to nonstop print the contents over and over, I just want to print when the file is updated.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Better to use OS functionality for that purposes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I watch a file for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pathlib import Path
import time


file = Path('myfile')

# print the current content
old_time = file.stat().st_mtime
print(file.read_text())

while True:
    # every second (time.sleep(1)) check if the modification time of the file has changed. If so, print the content of the file
    if file.stat().st_mtime != old_time:
        old_time = file.stat().st_mtime
        print(file.read_text())
    time.sleep(1)
```